# Need to convert os.system with subprocess.call

Tags: python-2.7

i need to convert os.system() to subprocess.call()

I have 2 complex commands executing inside os.system as (cmd1 +"&&"+cmd2), I need to convert it to subprocess.call() with shell=False(for security reasons)

example of my code :-

```
cmd1 ="echo paras"
cmd2 ="rm -rf paras1.txt"
os.system as (cmd1 +"&&"+cmd2)
```

I Tried:-

```
subprocess.call([cmd3,"&&",cmd4],shell=False)
subprocess.call(shlex.split(cmd3+ "&&" +cmd4),shell=False)
```

but failed in both cases, i need to know how can i run 2 commands inside subprocess.call() separated by  "&&" with shell=False.

Comment: You want to execute shell commands, but the commands are not executed by a shell beause of: `shell=False`

Comment: @MauriceMeyer okay, but is there any other way that i can execute these commands with shell=False, As if i run subprocess.call(shlex.split(cmd3),shell=false) then it gets executed,  Its just when i use 2 commands and with "&&" in between i am not able to do this with shell=False.

Comment: i want to do it with shell=False, so i need workaround for ( used in above code for os.system to be used in subprocess to run 2 commands at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the commands within a shell (for example bash):

```
import subprocess

shell = '/bin/bash'  # you may need to adjust the path! 
cmds = ['echo "foo"', '&&',  'echo "bar"']

cmd = [shell, '-c', ' '.join(cmds)]
print cmd
print subprocess.call(cmd, shell=False)
```

Output:

```
['/bin/bash', '-c', 'echo "foo" && echo "bar"']
foo
bar
0
```